# sshd tries reverse DNS lookups with UseDNS no

Tags: ssh, reverse-dns

sshd seems to almost always try to perform a reverse DNS lookup on new connections. For hosts without a PTR entry this causes delays of 5 seconds per query. Sometimes it accepts the connection immediately, sometimes it tries to resolve once, sometimes twice. I observed this using `tcpdump port 53` while trying to connect to the server. I have really no idea why it tries to lookup twice sometimes.

This seems to be a fairly frequent issue and the standard response is `UseDNS no` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. However, I already have this option set and sshd is still trying to perform these reverse lookups.

I found another suggestion [here](http://linux-tips.org/article/92/disabling-reverse-dns-lookups-in-ssh). I tried to add -u0 to /etc/default/ssh, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

I'm out of ideas at this point, any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Did you restart the service after making those changes?

Comment: Yes, of course. (-:

Comment: Try upping the sshd LogLevel to VERBOSE or DEBUG to see what's going on?

Comment: I intend to try that sometime at night when there are fewer connections from people...

Comment: Can you post your sshd_config? Testing with FreeBSD 9.1 and 9.2 indicates that with UseDNS set to no, and no other configuration item set that might cause a DNS lookup, no lookups occur.

Comment: If OpenSSH is built with tcpwrapper support, that can also cause reverse lookups for the client address depending on the tcpwrapper policy (/etc/hosts.{allow,deny} etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been a while, but it turned out that the lag disappeared the next time we rebooted the server. I have no idea what happened, but it must have been one of the things I tried and apparently just restarting sshd wasn't enough.

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays the most frequent culprit is GSSAPI:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

The other three culprits for Linux platform have been mentioned in other answer:

- add to `sshd` a command line option `-u0`
- set `UseDNS no`
- don't use `from=hostname` inside `authorized_keys` files

Answer (score 5):

Use DNS = no does not prevent sshd from performing DNS lookups, it prevents it from rejecting clients when PTR records don't match.

-u0 prevents sshd from logging DNS names in the utmp struct.

lookups might still happen depending one what a user has in their authorized_keys.

See this for a decent explanation:

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2006-November/030886.html

Comment: To be honest, I haven't even heard about there being a possibility to specify from=hostname in authorized_keys, so at least in the case of myself trying to log in, this is not in effect. Also, the lookup-induced lag happens *before* sshd logs the line Connection from <host> port <port> in syslog, which presumably means, before it learns what user is trying to log in.

Answer (score 1):

Modify those in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22,
UseDNS yes,
UsePAM no,
UseLogin no,

And make: service sshd restart

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was entries in the hosts.allow and/or hosts.deny files that caused it to do dns lookups. According to the documentation the same can happen for Allow and Deny directives in the config files.

Answer (score -2):

Also disable GSS auth can help with this issue.

Comment: This answer has already been given earlier.